# Problems with drools list not firing for all matched item

Tags: list, drools, rule-engine

I'm starting with drools engine. I tweaked their sample program. it doesn't seem to be working. No matter how many `MessageItem` I put inside `Message`, I always get one "Test" printed on the console.

Here is my list file :

```
package com.sample

import com.sample.Message;
import com.sample.MessageItem;

rule "Hello World"
    when
        m : Message( status == Message.HELLO, $mItems : messageItems)
    mi : MessageItem(message == m, item == "test") from $mItems
then
    System.out.println( "Test "); # This is printed only once.
    # code to update m and mi
    update( m );
    update (mi);
end

end
```

Here are my classes, I have ommitted the getters/setters

```
public static class Message {

    public static final int HELLO = 0;
    public static final int GOODBYE = 1;

    private String message;
    private List<MessageItem> messageItems = new ArrayList<MessageItem>();

    private int status;

}


public static class MessageItem {

    private String item;
    private Message message;        
}
```

Comment: I always get one "Test" printed on the console. System.out.println( "Test "); # This is printed only once. So what's your question?

Comment: why are you calling update() on the objects if they did not change? Also, assuming that you are inserting both Message and MessageItem objects into the working memory (best thing to do), you should remove the "from $mItems" from there.

Comment: @EdsonTirelli If I remove the `from $mItems` same result. Actually it happens that only the last MessageItem inserted into the working memory gets updated.

Comment: can you add to your question the code you are using to test the rule, with the data you are inserting into the session, plz?

Comment: @EdsonTirelli I see it now. If I remove `update( m )` it works as expected. With the `update (m)` call it does not pass the first condition after 1st pass. Thanks for your help.